# How to remove object by property in JSON array using MySQL functions?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Given the following JSON stored inside a MySQL `json` data type:

```
"users": [
    {
        "group": "manager",
        "userID": "a123"
    },
    {
        "group": "employee",
        "userID": "a456"
    }
]
```

How can I remove user object with `"userID": "a456"` without knowing its position in the array?

If we know the position then the following works:

```
$query = 'UPDATE jsontable SET
jsondata = JSON_REMOVE
(
    jsondata, 
    "$.users[1]"
);';
```

However, what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
$query = 'UPDATE jsontable SET
jsondata = JSON_REMOVE
(
    jsondata, 
    (
        JSON_SEARCH
        (
            jsondata, 
            "all",
            JSON_OBJECT("userID", "a456")
        )
    )
);';
```

The above produces a data truncated error for the `jsondata` column. Other variations such as putting the userID directly instead of `JSON_OBJECT` also produce errors.

What do I need to fix in the query to make `JSON_SEARCH` return the path to the specific object that I want to remove from the array?

Bearing in mind that it should *only* search inside of `users`, as there might be other properties on the main JSON object using those IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this `JSON_SEARCH` could work for you. It should **return the path** for you. The last parameter `'$**.users'` indicates to search only in paths called `users`

```
SELECT 
    JSON_SEARCH(jsondata, 'one', 'a456', null, '$**.users') 
    FROM jsontable
```

Find here a [Dbfiddle JSON_SEARCH](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dr7RuDLRBbguYaUqhhJFV6/0)

**UPDATE**

Combined statement with `JSON_REMOVE`, `JSON_SEARCH` and the `REPLACE` function which **unquotes** the result of JSON_SEARCH.

```
UPDATE jsontable
    SET jsondata = JSON_REMOVE( 
        jsondata, REPLACE( 
            JSON_SEARCH( jsondata, 'one', 'a456', null, '$**.users' )
            , '"'
            , ''
        ) 
      );
```

[DBFiddle with JSON_REMOVE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dr7RuDLRBbguYaUqhhJFV6/6)

*Additional Infos:*

- [MySQL JSON_SEARCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search)
- [MySQL JSON_REMOVE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-remove)
- [MySQL JSON PATH Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-path-syntax.html)

Comment: Thanks, do you mean using this `SELECT` inside of the update clause? If so it'll result in an invalid JSON path expression error - I'm not sure if this is syntax related or if it's just not possible to run a `SELECT JSON_SEARCH` inside of a `JSON_REMOVE` as its `path` parameter.

Comment: @Optimae a replace should do the trick. Take a look at the update.

Comment: Hey @Michael, thanks for updating, this still results in a `Data truncated for column 'jsondata' at row 1` error, I'll set up a dbfiddle though to share.

Comment: Thanks, although I still get data truncated errors it seems to be a PHP/PDO/localised issue and this fiddle does indeed work, so marking as correct!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Michael's answer.

To remove double quote he is using `REPLACE` function.
For this we can use [JSON_UNQUOTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote).

Moreover the solution will not work, because the path returned from [JSON_SEARCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) will be pointing to the search string passed. So it will remove the key value pair from the object instead of object.
So, to remove complete object we have to get the previous path of the json.

```
UPDATE jsontable
    SET jsondata = JSON_REMOVE( 
        jsondata, JSON_UNQUOTE(
            REPLACE( 
                JSON_SEARCH( jsondata, 'one', 'a456', null, '$**.users' )
                , '.userID'
                , ''
            )
        ) 
    );
```

As we need previous path I am Hardcoding it here.